# Error: Error establishing a database connection on wordpress when I search plugins

Tags: database, wordpress, docker-compose

my `wordpress` app have an error when I search install plugins using wordpress CLI.

`Error: Error establishing a database connection.`

I'm using Docker container.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wordpress');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'db:3306');
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

- docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Please format your question to make it more readable.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely its due to low php memory as well as file permission system. I recommend to contact hosting to fix this issue and if not possible then you can increase php memory and reset file permission to have it solved.

Comment: Hi, Devmaster,

I'm using a localhost